# How to workaround the Cross-thread operation not valid exception so we can leave already implemented code intact

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I want to update a gui widget's value in a handler function which is called in another thread under the hood:

```
    private void handle_PingMessage(Dictionary<string, object> msg)
    {
        string received_text = (string)msg["text"];
        label1.Text = received_text;
    }
```

...it throws the following exception:

```
Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

If I change the usage as:

```
    private void handle_PingMessage(Dictionary<string, object> msg)
    {
        string received_text = (string)msg["text"];
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label1.Text = received_text; }));
        }
        // do any other work here
    }
```

It works as expected.

I'm [handling the event firing process manually](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/blob/master/aktos-dcs-cs/actor.cs#L159-L166) as follows:

```
                        string event_name = "event_" + key;
                        EventInfo handler_event = this.GetType().GetEvent(event_name);
                        var event_delegate = (MulticastDelegate)this.GetType().GetField(event_name, 
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this);
                        foreach (var handler in event_delegate.GetInvocationList())
                        {
                            handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, new object[] { ((JObject)payload_dict[key]).ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>() });
                        }
```

Is there anything to do with the manual event firing part of the code in order to let user have the clearer usage somehow:

```
    private void handle_PingMessage(Dictionary<string, object> msg)
    {
        string received_text = (string)msg["text"];
        label1.Text = received_text;
    }
```

## Edit

The full source code of this example usage is [here](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/blob/11e761fb1ec7867d499e259b239161482104543d/examples/gui-example/gui-example/Form1.cs).

## Edit-2

Fully working commit after solution is [here](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/blob/3b9b9264cf768880d09368ac4537c0ff942a8c91/examples/gui-example/gui-example/Form1.cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor of your object grab the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` and then when you fire the event post the event invocation to that synchronization context:

```
public class YourPingClass
{
    private SynchronizationContext syncContext;
    public YourPingClass()
    {
        syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? 
            new SynchronizationContext();
    }

    private void FireEvent()
    {
        string event_name = "event_" + key;
        EventInfo handler_event = this.GetType().GetEvent(event_name);
        var event_delegate = (MulticastDelegate)this.GetType().GetField(event_name, 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this);
        foreach (var handler in event_delegate.GetInvocationList())
        {
            syncContext.Post(_ => handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, 
                new object[] { ((JObject)payload_dict[key]).ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>() }));
        }
    }
}
```

If you want, you may also want to allow the user of your type to explicitly provide a synchronization context (or equivalent) through a method or property setter, but if your users are going to be creating your object from the UI thread (which is typical for custom UI components like this) then you can just capture the current sync context yourself so they don't need to explicitly do anything.

Comment: I edited the base class [as you suggested](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/commit/48b4e97ce72a1b5129368ec38d7f27ed41244d86) but it still gives the same error.

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/commit/705a8018a41eb704fafedb0112a904a687a60aea) works as expected. I needed to assign `syncContext` as `dcs.syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current` in Form class. One more goal is saving the users from defining `the_comm_object.syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current` in their Form class.

Comment: ...and the question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801569/how-to-get-synchronizationcontext-on-object-creation).

Comment: @ceremcem This would only work if the object you're using here is created from a UI context.  If its not, then the context would need to be passed in explicitly, as I said in the answer.

Comment: With the [last solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801569/how-to-get-synchronizationcontext-on-object-creation?noredirect=1#comment57348870_34801569), all problems are solved. Working commit is [here](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/blob/3b9b9264cf768880d09368ac4537c0ff942a8c91/examples/gui-example/gui-example/Form1.cs). Thank you.