# How to detect if an object is created under class definition or in class' constructor

Tags: c#

I have designed a library class (`Foo`) and I need to use this class like:

```
class Bar
{
    Foo foo; 

    public Bar() 
    {
        foo = new Foo(); 
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

If I create `foo` object right under class:

```
class Bar
{
    Foo foo = new Foo(); 

    public Bar() 
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

then my `Bar` application (think that this is a windows `Form` application) works anyway, but when a specific situation is arised it throws an exception (`Cross-thread operation not valid` excecption in my real case).

So I'm warning my folks about this usage hint: "You MUST initialize your `Foo` type object in your app's constructor."

Is there any way to add a code in `Foo` class that will save users remember this rule, thus make the compiler throw an exception if an object from `Foo` is not initialized in `Bar`'s constructor?

## Long Story

While not knowing C# well, I needed do port our [dcs library](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs) into C#, which is [over here](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs)

When I tried to set a GUI object's variable in another thread, I faced with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799854/how-to-workaround-the-cross-thread-operation-not-valid-exception-so-we-can-leave/34800114#34800114) problem. So I needed to synchronize them somehow, as  I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801569/how-to-get-synchronizationcontext-on-object-creation) and found a right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801569/how-to-get-synchronizationcontext-on-object-creation?noredirect=1#comment57348870_34801569).

So my application works in a way exactly I wanted it to be, and the fully working example application is [here](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/blob/3b9b9264cf768880d09368ac4537c0ff942a8c91/examples/gui-example/gui-example/Form1.cs).

But, if I initialize that `foo` variable right under the class definition (as in the first example) the `SynchronizationContext.Current` variable refers to something else from the `Bar` application's own `SynchronizationContext.Current` variable. That's why, the application does not work when something happens ([do not ask what it is](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-cs/blob/3b9b9264cf768880d09368ac4537c0ff942a8c91/aktos-dcs-cs/actor.cs#L168-L171))

That's why, rather than warning users and forcing them remember that they MUST initialize that `foo` object in a class' constructor they want to use, I'm looking for a way to warn them on demand by adding something in `Foo` class.

Comment: Did you intend for Bar() to be a constructor of the Bar type? With the return type (void) defined it's just a method now. Did you mean just "public Bar()"?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What is the "specific situation" that breaks your code?  In what way does it fail?  What exactly are you trying to do and how is this not working?

Comment: How does this at all make a difference?

Comment: That's why your class should have a constructor.

Comment: Please see the "Long Story" part

Comment: @David Please see the "Long Story" part of the question I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the compiler throw an exception ...

NO, cause both initialization type is valid. But you can create your own Exception type and throw it if not initialized inside constructor like

```
class Bar
{
Foo foo = null; 

public void Bar() 
{
   if(foo == null)
   {
    foo = new Foo(); 
   }
  else
   {
       throw new Exception("foo not initialized in constructor");
    ...
}
```

Only other way to throw a compiler error is to use a `code analysis rule`. You can create a `FxCop` rule for this and apply that which will throw a build error if failed.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention that I need to perform this check in `Foo` class in order not to make `Bar` class' author disturbed. `Foo` is a kind of library class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is, but can you not just use a lazy loaded property and then it doesn't matter where it's called from:

```
private Foo _foo;
public Foo foo
{
    get
    {
        if (_foo == null)
        {
            _foo = new Foo();
        }
        return _foo;
    }
}
```

Then the first time you call it then it will be instantiated.

Comment: You meant this to be a property and so missing `get` accessor.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It's been a long day :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to determine this case in `Foo` class, I'm sorry about that.